# Android Studio Iguana 'App not installed' error

Tags: android-studio

After upgrading Android Studio to Iguana. When I run app, build starts executing and build successful after that android studio through error message Installation failed suggested action: Retry.

I've tried several solutions incl.

- Clean Build.
- Invalidate Cache and Restart.
- Redownloaded Android SDK
- Uninstall and Redownload Android Studio with Clear all android files from my mac

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here. Also tried about everything.

Now reverted to Hedgehog and the problem is gone.

[edit] Google now has a P1 bug for this: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/327740540

Comment: Same here in the end I also downloaded Hedgehog from [Android Studio download archives](https://developer.android.com/studio/archive) and it's working fine. There are still bugs in the Android Studio Iguana stable release

Answer (score 1):

Go to Edit Configurations change deploy Default APK to APK from app bundle

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue you have to remove space in APK file naming if you are giving a specific name to your build APK example.

this is my old code which is creating the issue

```
variant.outputs.all { output ->
        def project = "Project Name"
        def SEP = " "
        def buildType = variant.buildType.name
        def version = variant.versionName
        def flavor = variant.productFlavors[0].name

        def newApkName = project + SEP + flavor + SEP + version + ".apk"
        outputFileName = new File(newApkName)
    }
```

And this is the solution

```
variant.outputs.all { output ->
        def project = "ProjectName"
        def SEP = "_"
        def buildType = variant.buildType.name
        def version = variant.versionName
        def flavor = variant.productFlavors[0].name

        def newApkName = project + SEP + flavor + SEP + version + ".apk"
        outputFileName = new File(newApkName)
    }
```

I have removed all the spaces from the final APK name and everything is working fine.